# Which of the two will be faster

Tags: php

Which of the two will be faster and how can do such measurements

```
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
 $totalikes = count($post["Like"]);
 $totacomments = count($post["Comment"]);
 $max = ($totalikes < $totacomments )? $totacomments  : $totalikes;
 for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++)
 {
  if(isset($post["Like"][$i]))
   $users[] = $post["Like"][$i]["user_id"];
  if(isset($post["Comment"][$i]))
   $users[] = $post["Comment"][$i]["user_id"];
 }
}
```

or

```
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
 foreach ($post["Like"] as $like)
 {
  $users[] = $like["user_id"];
 }
 foreach ($post["Comment"] as $comment)
 {
  $users[] = $comment["user_id"];
 }
}
```

Which of the two is better

Comment: Just for clarity I would choose the second. Performance difference is probably negligible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method.

First method will have overhead if the count of `$post['like'] & $post['comment']` is different

**PS:** first method does not do the same thing as second method does ...

total loop in method A = `2 x max array size`
total loop in method B = `size of array A+size of array B`

As for the `$users`, should be the same for both method

Comment: why what's the mistake/ diffrence